# Background of my modal doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I try to use a modal using Iframe for connexion / inscription on my web site

Html :

```
<div class="modal" id="ays-popin-connexion" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body" aria-hidden="true">
        <iframe src="***" id="iframe1" class="popup" frameborder="0" aria-hidden="true">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.modal{
        height:650px;
        width:950px;
        left:30%;
        top:10%;
        opacity: 0.8;
        z-index: 4589365;
    }
    .modal-body{
        height:650px;
        width:950px;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        max-height:2000px;
    }
    .popup{
        height:650px;
        width:950px;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
```

Javascript :

```
window.onload = function()
{  
    $("#ays-menu a").on("click",function(event){
          if(this.text == "CONNEXION");
          {
          console.log($(this).attr('href'));
         $("#ays-popin-connexion").toggle(1500);
           console.log(this);
          }
     });
}
```

My modal appear as you can see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qwQ0.png

But i want the background outside of my modal to become fade or grey and i have really no idea how to change it

By the way an other question how can i tell to my modal that when i click outside of my modal the modal close because i supposed this was native

If you want to try by yourself just go to dev.appyourself.com and click on the red button "connexion" .

Comment: You need to create your modal inside a container that is 100% width/height of the windows browser. Add opacity+hide/show it with the  modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty div with a class of `blanket`.

Give `.blanket` this style:

```
.blanket{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:4580000 /*lower than the modal but higher than body*/
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:none;
 }
```

Then the `jquery`.

```
$("#ays-menu a").on("click",function(event){
      if(this.text == "CONNEXION");
      {
          $(".blanket").show();
          $("#ays-popin-connexion").toggle(1500);
      }
 });

$('.blanket').click(function(){
    $('.modal').hide();
    $(this).hide();
};
```

This is just rough and you will need to work out what works best for you.

Also, it's best if you get the height and width right for the login, as it has horrible scrollbars, or alternatively use `overflow:hidden;` on `.modal`.

Comment: @AlexandreSchmitz It might be better if you use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`, but it's up to you :)

Comment: And using bootstrap like this $('#ays-popin-connexion').modal(); will works ?

Comment: Should do @AlexandreSchmitz

Comment: What is the best for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Here my modified  code, which help you.

```
 <div class="modal" id="ays-popin-connexion" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-body" aria-hidden="true">
            <iframe src="***" id="iframe1" class="popup" frameborder="0" aria-hidden="true">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--   Add for modal backdrop -->
    <div class="modal-backdrop" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**Here My css For modal-backdrop**

```
.modal-backdrop {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1030;
background-color: #000;
}
```

**Javascript code here :-**

```
window.onload = function()
{  
    $("#ays-menu a").on("click",function(event){
          if(this.text == "CONNEXION");
          {
          console.log($(this).attr('href'));
         $("#ays-popin-connexion").toggle(1500);
         $(".modal-backdrop").show();
           console.log(this);
          }
     });
/************Click outside pop up close the pop up ***********/
   $(".modal-backdrop").click(function(){
      $("#ays-popin-connexion").hide();
   });
}
```